# Android: Action Bar with Different Action Buttons

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using Android Tab Navigation using Combat Action Bar. I have implemented Custom Action Bar.
Now i want to add different buttons to Action Bar According to tabs. i want some thing like that. [image]

In some fragment i need this button, while in other i need different button.

Any Help Will be Appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom action bar to add number of buttons.
Try This:-
Link Here: http://www.djbp.co.uk/android-actionbar-adding-buttons/

Comment: We Have to Support Api 10 As Well.